# What Linux distribution has the most up-to-date packages?

Tags: linux, package-management

Ubuntu's release schedule is just too slow. I want the absolute latest version of everything. Even if it's slightly unstable. Which distribution will give me this without having to manually install everything from source?

Comment: Maybe you should add a "Bleeding-edge" tag there as well.

Comment: Sure, why not.

Comment: [NixOS](https://nixos.org), see [Repology's statistics](https://repology.org/repositories/statistics/pnewest), sorted by percentage of newest packages. **Termux** wins but it's not really a "Linux distribution", with [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org) following closely after NixOs

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update**: This answer does not help anymore.
As noted by Ethan in comments below the `OSWatershed.org` site has changed hands. There are multiple other places still pointing to that domain name like this answer does `:-)`.

I would have deleted this answer however it is a good memory of such a site's existence. Maybe there is another similar site or someone might fork and update this one from its source -- (see https://github.com/tannewt/open-source-watershed).

Meanwhile, ArchLinux continues to be at the top.
Another place that might be useful: https://distrowatch.com/packages.php

---

Look at the [**Open Source Watershed**](http://oswatershed.org/) page.

> **OpenSourceWatershed** is a project aimed at understanding the relationship between distributions (downstream) and the individual software components (upstream). It is the basis for a larger study of distributions and their evolution. It is **distrology**. In the future, more distro oriented statistics will be available. More details are below. For now search in the top right for your favorite package to see how up to date the different distributions. Or look at the right to see what new releases happened in the last 24 hours.

[Arch Linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=Arch) is presently at the top.

But, when you have a specific development project of interest,
I think, its better to track the source straight -- rather than depend on disto updates.

Comment: Well that about sums it up. It's time to give Arch a try.

Comment: is this answer still valid?

Comment: Should probably fix that link, it links to a site about the actual, literal watershed now.

Comment: Use https://repology.org/ instead

Answer (score 4):

debian unstable

dozens, sometimes hundreds of new and updated packages every day.  if you want bleeding edge packages, this is it.

Answer (score 3):

there are some distributions that work with a rolling release schedule,meaning that when a certain piece of software is released,it is included in the distribution once tested and found compatible with the distribution

examples of those distros include Arch Linux,Gentoo and PCLinuxOS

Comment: And among those, which is the most likely to have the latest version of something obscure like say, the Python bindings for CouchDB, the day it comes out? ;)

Comment: Gentoo sometimes gets new releases out the next day, and sometimes they have long delays. The latter is more likely for large programs or core system packages (like Python). But you can usually get around it by using an overlay (third-party repository) and/or by specifying that you're willing to use an untested version of the package.

Comment: @ Daniel : I don't know the exact package you're talking about,but pretty much everything is presesnt in the AUR,a user-maintained repository

Answer (score 1):

The timing of versions of packages in different distributions is based on the package maintainer at each said distribution. Therefore to keep absolutely up-to-date in all apps you'll need to use multiple distros. Virtualization is the easiest way to do this. Using virtualbox in seamless mode makes it seem, visually, like all the apps are running in your host.

Still, if you want cutting edge you'll need to compile. Some apps aren't available in any distro until released as "stable". Some apps are never available in any distribution.

I wouldn't recommend using any unstable distro version without virtualization. Keep your host running a released distro that's reasonable up to date like Fedora, Arch, Gentoo (you didn't want to compile though) or whatever distro you're most comfortable with that supports the virtualizer you choose. Then install the beta versions of whatever distros you need in virtuals to satisfy the range of apps you're interested in.

Currently most distros will not remain fully stable and usable throughout the alpha/beta cycle until release. Recent beta distros that have broken during upgrades include Ubuntu karmic, Fedora 12, Mandriva 2010 and OpenSuse 11.2. Typical problems are proprietary video and hardware drivers, kernel boot problems and gui system configuration tools. Often these problems can be fixed by patching and compiling yourself or waiting a few days or weeks until another update fixes things. As the distro gets to release candidate stage stability increases but application updates fall behind.

Answer (score 1):

Manjaro is the most up to date distro you can get, it also supports proprietary drivers so no need to worry about breaking it.

it is also really fast, definitely quicker than Ubuntu, only bad point is that some packages are put together on Ubuntu so they take a bit of tweaking to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint is pretty good, but as was said, the major updates of programs don't usually wait for the next release.
I didn't want to wait for a couple of new releases like Firfox 3.5, etc and I went straight to mozilla and d/l it and with help from the experts here, I was able to install the Firefox 3.5 and now I am a happy camper again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a package the day it is released, compile it from source, if a few days delay is not a problem, than debian unstable.

Answer (score 0):

First, some distributions are release based and some are rolling edged.  Comparing them is unfair.  For example, compare arch with debian stable.

I think Funtoo goes further than any other distributions.  (Gentoo as a source oriented distribution always features blooding packages.  And Funtoo is the develop branch of Gentoo.  Enough said.)