# Best Linux Distribution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, opensuse

hi I am right now on Windows 7 alongwith a newly bought Dell Laptop .I want to install Linux too .
I have been using Ubuntu 10.10 before . now I want to try a different flavour in Linux which has a good audio/video options & is security enhanced .

Right now I have the following distributions :
Ubuntu 10.10
OpenSuse 11.0
Fedora 13 .

among the three mentioned above which might be the best to learn out things n get more close to linux .I am a student & eager to learn a lot of new things .... so which of the above would be the best for me ?

Comment: Questions of this kind have been asked and answered a lot here, see e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/1967/good-linux-distributions-for-newbies, http://superuser.com/questions/30052/linux-distributions-comparison, http://superuser.com/questions/31096/what-linux-distribution-has-the-most-up-to-date-packages, http://superuser.com/questions/172278/linux-distribution-with-good-oss-support. You should be able to find enough input there.

Comment: this is a very debatable topic. I use Ubuntu 10.10 on my machines and RedHat at work. Depending on how ambitious you are try compiling gentoo =)

Comment: Agreed. The three distributions you propose are not primarily targeted at developers or people interested in learning more, but at people who want something that just works. Gentoo has been the most educational for me.

Comment: Arch or Kali.  Both are the most complicated and hardest to use.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this....Best Linux Distribution is a loaded and flame inciting heading.  If you want to learn avoid flame-wars.  LFS or DFS.  LFS is better for learning EVERYTHING.  DFS focuses on debian package management.  The fedora/suse thing focuses on RPM.  So, if i were you recognized your configured options I would go with LFS.  You will surely understand linux more, and the only remaining issue is package management.

Comment: I'd spend my reputation to vote down flamey posts without thinking twice. ;-)

Comment: I get your position, but I'm currently getting down-voted by people being dense when even the person posing the question say it's a valid answer.  It's irritating to be sure...and why I contemplate leaving the stack system.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very subjective matter. I can tell you that I learned the most from using [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/main/en/about.xml), which requires you to compile software locally, potentially giving it a performance advantage. The documentation and community were solid during my time using it.

At the moment I'm very content with [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/about/); once it's set up it requires minimal maintenance, while still being current because it's *[rolling release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release)*.

**From the three you mentioned** I would pick Ubuntu any day. I simply love the Debian package management, structure and philosophy combined with the regular releases, easier hardware detection and large community of Ubuntu.

**Edit, four years later:** A lot has changed in Ubuntu-land, and now my every-day use distro of choice is Linux Mint, for the same reasons.

Overall, if I had to pick one distribution for the rest of my life, I think I'd choose [Debian](http://www.debian.org/).

Comment: Please no one comment on how the Debian philosophy is sort of lost in Ubuntu. I'm aware. :-)

Comment: +1 for Arch and Gentoo. The way to go to learn new things, but not the best choice for regular every-day use I'd say.